# Android App not asking for permissions when installing from playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions

I made an android app and published it on play store. I mentioned all the app specific required permissions in manifest.xml file, But when I am installing it from playstore it not asking the permissions like it asked for other apps. 
I found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701792/android-app-not-asking-for-permissions-when-installing) But did'nt get what I am looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agrawalgaurav.www.nighttorch">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, the behavior that you are seeing is expected, as you have to ask for the `CAMERA` permission at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the app in a phone running Android version 6.0 or above where the user should be requested permission on runtime and not at install time

Refer this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes I am running it on Android version 7.0 but its not asking even at runtime

Comment: It won't ask by itself. you have to write the code to do that. The reference I have added makes that clear.

Comment: Sorry buddy I dont have sufficient reputation, I will Once I got 15+

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android 6 or higher permissions will be asking in runtime. Some permissions probably will not be asking in runtime, for example Internet permission, because they are from [Normal Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) group.

Comment: Yes I am running it on Android version 7.0 but its not asking even at runtime